# Correct type for a function that updates either a d3 transition or selection

Tags: typescript, d3.js, definitelytyped

I am trying to figure out the right typings for some TypeScript d3 code that updates the positions of some svg elements.  The code can either run with no transition (i.e. it should update immediately) or with a transition.  I've written a helper method to perform the update, but I am having trouble figuring out the correct type.  My code works like this:

```
const circles = group.selectAll('circle').data(points);
if (transitionsEnabled) {
    updateCircles(circles.transition().duration(1000));
} else {
    updateCircles(circles);
}

function updateCircles(circles: d3.Selection<d3.BaseType, Point, d3.BaseType, {}> {
    circles
       .attr('cx', (d: Point) => d.x)
       .attr('cy', (d: Point) => d.y)
       .attr('r', 5);
}
```

This gives me an error: `Argument of type 'Transition<BaseType, Point, BaseType, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Selection<BaseType, Point, BaseType, {}>` on the call where transitions are enabled.

Switching the type of the function parameter to Transition creates an equivalent error.  I can solve it by giving the function parameter a type of

```
d3.Selection<d3.BaseType, Point, d3.BaseType, {}>|d3.Transition<d3.BaseType, Point, d3.BaseType, {}>
```

But that seems ugly.  Is there a better way to type this method?  I could create a type alias to make things a little smoother, but that seems like something that should already exist.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is an ugly solution.  You are attempting to pass one type into your function or another type.  This seems to be [the exact use case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) for the union operator.

Comment: My particular concern is that what I'm doing should be a common use case for d3, and I am surprised that the typing is awkward for it.  It seems like there should be some kind of type like SelectionOrTransition already defined that I can use.  Alternately, I wonder if I am doing the wrong thing, as indicated by the idea that selection and transition are not interchangeable.